# Import "six.moves.urllib.request" could not be resolved from source Pylance (reportMissingModuleSource)

Tags: python, import, urllib, six

In MacBook vscode, I get the **Import "six.moves.urllib.request" could not be resolved from source Pylance (reportMissingModuleSource)** error. How do I fix it?

(already pip install but I try uninstall and again install)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.